# Syntax error: Python for loop and if statement

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

Novice here!!

I am trying to search through a FASTA for a specific DNA sequence, but I keep getting a sytax error. The if statements work outside of the for loop, so I think it is how I have put them in, can anybody see the syntax error here, I can't work it out:

```
#!/bin/python

#My Mimp_finder

import re

from Bio import SeqIO


for seq in SeqIO.parse("Focub_mimp12rm_Chang_mimps.faa", "fasta"):
    print(seq.id)
    print(len(seq)                               
    if re.search(r"CAGTGGG..GCAA[TA]AA", seq):
        result_start = re.search(r"CAGTGGG..GCAA[TA]AA", seq)
        match_1_start = result_start.start()
    elif re.search(r"TT[TA]TTGC..CCCACTG", seq):
        result_end = re.search(r"TT[TA]TTGC..CCCACTG", seq)
        match_2_end = result_end.end()

        mimp_lenth = match_2_end - match_1_start

    print('---------------------------\n\n')
    if mimp_lenth < 400 :
    print('Mimp found at postion ' + str(match_1_start) + ' and ' + str(match_2_end) + ' in the sequence: \n\n' + seq + '. \n\nThe $
    print('\n\n---------------------------\n\n')
```

Returned:

```
File "./My_mimp_finder.py", line 16
    if re.search(r"CAGTGGG..GCAA[TA]AA", seq):
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python version 3.8.3

Comment: Could you please reduce your code to minimum needed to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hint: A syntax error is often above the place pointed to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parenthesis missing in the second print statement

```
print(len(seq)
```

should be

```
print(len(seq))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code. One is already pointed out by @I like coding above.

The reason for your error is in line above the line 16 where error is reported . You are missing closing braces for print statement.

```
print(len(seq) -- > print(len(seq))
```

Answer (score 0):

Side Note, there is also an issue with indentation.

After your "if" statement:

```
if mimp_lenth < 400 :
```

There needs to be an indentation otherwise you'll get an indentation error.

```
#!/bin/python

#My Mimp_finder

import re

from Bio import SeqIO


for seq in SeqIO.parse("Focub_mimp12rm_Chang_mimps.faa", "fasta"):
    print(seq.id)
    print(len(seq)                               
    if re.search(r"CAGTGGG..GCAA[TA]AA", seq):
        result_start = re.search(r"CAGTGGG..GCAA[TA]AA", seq)
        match_1_start = result_start.start()
    elif re.search(r"TT[TA]TTGC..CCCACTG", seq):
        result_end = re.search(r"TT[TA]TTGC..CCCACTG", seq)
        match_2_end = result_end.end()

        mimp_lenth = match_2_end - match_1_start

    print('---------------------------\n\n')
    if mimp_lenth < 400 :
         print('Mimp found at postion ' + str(match_1_start) + ' and ' + str(match_2_end) + ' in the sequence: \n\n' + seq + '. \n\nThe $


    print('\n\n---------------------------\n\n')
```

Comment: No, indentation errors produce an IndentationError (or semantic errors).

Comment: @MichaelButscher Oh good point, my fault. I will edit my answer once I figure out the syntax error, but there is an indentation error as well.